# Perl: Need to match a pattern

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a variable containing a string.

```
$name="mak -o create.pl -n create.txt";
```

Now I want to match a pattern in which I can get the value as create.pl which will always be followed by -o. That is , this is mandatory that this will occur always like this "-o create.pl"  But instead of "create" there could be any name like this but the extension will always be ".pl"

```
$name="mak -o string.pl -n create.txt"; # or it could be
$name="mak -o name.pl -n create.txt";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`/-o ([^\s]*)\s/`
```

Above will do :

```
> echo "mak -o create.pl -n create.txt" | perl -lne 'm/-o ([^\s]*)\s/;print $1'
create.pl
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay !! You always give good replies so quickly. I had asked before also, at that time you were the person to give answer very quickly. Thanks for your support always !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the variable by space.

```
my $name="mak -o name.pl -n create.txt";

my @cmd = split (/\s+/, $name);

for (my $i = 0; $i <@cmd; $i++) {
    if ($cmd[$i] eq "-o") {
        print $cmd[$i+1];
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Liked ur ans using split.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
/-o\s(.*?)\.pl/
```

`$1` will have the matched name.

Answer (score 0):

Using split :Dont need to worried about script name, split will take care of it.

```
use strict;

my $name="mak -o name.pl -n create.txt";

my $test = join( " ", (split /\s+/, $name)[1,2] );

print $test;
```

output:

```
-o name.pl
```

Comment: Hi, I think you didn't get my question, because it could be placed anywhere in the string, the only thing which will be stable is that pattern "-o name.pl". But according to this it would take particular values at those positions. Thanks for your support.